# Use update cursor in arcpy to count number of points within each polygon

Tags: arcpy, cursor, stopiteration

I have two shapefiles. One contains many points across a state. The other is all the counties within the state. I would like to do two things:

1. use a cursor to count how many points are in each county and then populate a new field with those data; and

   2. create a true/false field in which true = the county contains more than two points.

I started the first one but was unsuccessful, so the second I'm not sure how to accomplish. This is what I have so far...

```
import arcpy

points = r"C:\Users\points"
counties = r"C:\Users\counties"
#create new fields
arcpy.AddField_management(counties, "numOfPoints", "LONG", field_length = 10)
arcpy.AddField_management(counties, "hasTwoPoints", "LONG", field_length = 10)

points_lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(points,r'in_memory\points_lyr')
counties_lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(counties,r'in_memory\counties_lyr')
# Create an update cursor to access and update states features
#NAME has names of counties and numPoints will be populated with number of points 
fields = ['NAME','numOfPoints','hasTwoPoints']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(counties_lyr,fields) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        county = row[0]
        where = '"NAME" = \'{}\''.format(county)
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(counties_lyr,'NEW_SELECTION',where)
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(points_lyr,'INTERSECT',counties_lyr)
        number_of_points = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(counties_lyr).getOutput(0))
        row[1] = number_of_points
        cur.updateRow(row)
print('Operation complete.')
```

The current script works, but it populates the field 'numOfPoints' with all 1 values which is not correct.

then at the end to add the true/false based on the output to be a stand alone script,

```
fields2 = ['numOfPoints','hasTwoPoints']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(counties_lyr,fields2) as cur:
   for row in cur:
       if row[0] > 1: row[1] = 'TRUE'
   else: row[1] = 'FALSE'
   cur.updateRow(row)
```

I get this error: StopIteration: iteration not started

Comment: Can you add a message pop-up or print the contents of your variables where, number_of_points, and row[1]?  This may help you troubleshoot the problem.  You can delete this message or print command once you've narrowed down and fixed the issue.

Also, where you assign number_of_points, it appears you may be getting the count of the number of counties selected, not the count of the rigs_lyr layer.

Comment: You can use the spatial join tool to create a new shapefile.  The resulting shapefile will have a new attribute listing the number of points in each polygon. Then use a select by attribute and a field calculation to identify those records with a count of two or more.  If you still want to use the Python approach look at geometry objects which include a method to return point counts in polygons.  This approach will work faster than all the selections you have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got one line messed up:

When you calculate number_of_points, you want to GetCount the points_lyr, not the counties_lyr.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(counties_lyr,fields) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        county = row[0]
        where = '"NAME" = \'{}\''.format(county)
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(counties_lyr,'NEW_SELECTION',where)
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(points_lyr,'INTERSECT',counties_lyr)
        number_of_points = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(points_lyr).getOutput(0))
        row[1] = number_of_points
        cur.updateRow(row)
print('Operation complete.')
```

To do the second part of your question, you've got to clear all the selections:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(counties_lyr, "CLEAR_SELECTION")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(points_lyr, "CLEAR_SELECTION")

fields2 = ['numofpoints','has2points']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(counties_lyr,fields2) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        if row[0] > 1:
            row[1] = 1
        else:
            row[1] = 0
        cur.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: You were right. Thanks. And how would I populate a new field if the previous calculation was greater than or equal to 2? Meaning the county has more than  1 point in it...

Comment: Below the cur.updateRow(row), I would add: 

    if row[1] > 1:
        row[2] = 1
    else:
        row[2] = 0
    cur.updateRow(row)

Comment: With this code, it only populates the last row in the table. But above is another set of stand alone code but it's giving an error message.

Comment: Check out the edits above - it works now.